# Texshop problem: pdflatex does not exist, reinstalling mactex 2019 didn't work

Tags: pdftex, mactex

I just upgraded my mac to high sierra from snow leopard recently so I am encountering the same problem from a few years ago. I uninstalled MacTex 2014 and installed the new MacTex 2019 and the problem persists,  so the message is:

> /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/mactex and follow the instructions to install MacTeX or BasicTeX.

Some posts referred to https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf but this doc no longer exists. It's possible that I didn't uninstall the 2014 version completely . I uninstalled following https://tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html but I don't think I completed the steps for TeX Distribution Data Structure and Ghostscript.

Comment: Look in your TeXShop preferences, under Engines. The path settings should be `/Library/TeX/texbin`  and `/usr/local/bin` (for Distiller). Restart TeXShop to have them take effect.

Comment: @AlanMunn worked thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct path for a TeXShop needs to be set in the TeXShop Preferences -> Engine panel.  The two paths should be set to `/Library/TeX/texbin` and `/usr/local/bin` (for Distiller).

[image: TeXShop engine preferences]